# Select half of rows in each group in Excel pivot table

Tags: excel

I have a table in Excel with about 30,000 rows.  I grouped them based on a column value in a pivot table.

I am trying to run A/B tests on these rows, so I want to pull out half of the rows from each pivot table grouping.

Is there a straightforward way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

1. Add a numerical field to your table thats goes from 1 to 30 000 for each row
2. Slide this field into your pivot as ROWS, You can now see your newly added column
3. On your pivot table, click on the arrow pointing down at the right of your newly added field.
4. Click on Label Filters.
5. Click on Greater Than...
6. For the sack of your example, to divide your table in half it should be 15000..
7. Half of your values should now be hidden and the upper half of your pivot table remains.

You can get the lower half using the Less Than.. option, etc..

Comment: I might be misunderstanding what you're writing, but isn't this a solution for selecting half of the whole list?  I have grouped the list into "n" groups and I am trying to split each of those n groups into half.

Comment: So you want to keep the datas inside your pivot table?

Comment: There, i edited my answer. Hope this one actually helps you :)